# Why does my form post function opens my .pl file instead executing it?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, perl, svg

I have a `PERL` script *download.pl* which should be executed when a button is pressed. It is used to download an SVG.

But when the button is pressed, the website shows me the content of the perl script instead of executing it. Why is this and how do I fix it?

This code is what is called when I press my button:

```
function callOnButtonClick(){
            var svg = document.getElementById("mainSVG");
            // Extract the data as SVG text string
            var svg_xml = (new XMLSerializer).serializeToString(svg);
            console.log(svg_xml);

            var form = document.getElementById("svgform");
            form['output_format'].value = "svg";
            form['data'].value = svg_xml ;
            form.submit();
}
```

This is the form I use to execute my *download.pl* file which should initiate a download.

```
<form id="svgform" method="post" action="download.pl">
 <input type="hidden" id="output_format" name="output_format" value="">
 <input type="hidden" id="data" name="data" value="">
</form>
```

Comment: You have these two lines? AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl
    Options FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI

Comment: No I don't have those? Where are they supposed to be? I'm sorry for not knowing much, I'm and very new to using perl.

Comment: it is in httpd.conf, see my answer below. Djizeus's answer already pointed you the right direction, if you didn't get him then you probably should have read the documentations first.

Answer (score 3):

This is a problem of configuration of your web server. It seems it is not aware that it should execute perl scripts and return the response, rather than just serve the file.

Have a look at the documentation of your web server to see how to configure it to execute perl scripts, or post more information about your server and what you have tried if you already have configured your server but it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Edit your httpd.conf. 
You should replace your  part with below. Replace X with your directory.

```
<Directory "X:\webserver\cgi-bin" />
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl
    Options FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
    AllowOverride None  
</Directory>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm assuming I have to change the head of my file. Current it has the following: `#!/usr/bin/env perl
=pod`

Comment: `=pod` is on another line.

Comment: Yes, change the cgi-bin directory accordingly, and make sure you have read-write recursive permissions to cgi-bin directory and your cgi script.